# How can I toggle display with vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want buttons visibility to be toggled with `display:none` when i click `.button1` I tried if statements but not working n' also how can i bind two or more buttons one style with vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <div class="button1" @click="showOthers()">1</div>
      <div class="button2" v-bind:style="{ display }">2</div>
      <div class="button3" v-bind:style="{ display }">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
  data(){
      return {
        display:'none'
      }
  },
  methods: {
    showOthers: function() {
      this.display = "inline-block"
      if(this.display == "inline-block"){
        this.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#buttons div{
  margin-top:5px;
  text-align: center;
  width:40px;
  height:35px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius:15px;
  color:white;
}
#buttons div:first-child{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an `if`/`else` in `showOthers`? Otherwise you're testing whether `this.display` is `inline-block` just after setting it to `inline-block`. Any reason why you're not using `v-if` or `v-show` for this?

Comment: you're setting `this.display` to `"inline-block"` then checking `if(this.display == "inline-block")`, this if condition will always be true

Comment: you just want to toggle the other button's display when click on button `1` right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you just want to toggle the display of other button when clicking on button `1`. 
I would simply use `v-if` and toggle the value of the bonded variable inside `v-if` when clicking button `1`

Something like

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   data :{
        display:false
  },
  methods: {
    showOthers: function() {
      this.display = !this.display;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#buttons div{
  margin-top:5px;
  text-align: center;
  width:40px;
  height:35px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius:15px;
  color:white;
}
#buttons div:first-child{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div id="buttons">
      <div class="button1" @click="showOthers()">1</div>
      <div class="button2" v-if="display">2</div>
      <div class="button3" v-if="display">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1- To toggle visibility you only have to change the value of display, then button2 and button3 will be updated.

```
<div id="buttons">
   <div class="button1" @click="showOthers()">1</div>
   <div class="button2" v-show="display == 'inline-block' ? false: true">2</div>
   <div class="button3" v-show="display == 'inline-block' ? false : true">3</div>
</div>
```

...

```
   showOthers: function() { this.display = "inline-block" };
```

2- Binding style in Vuejs is like standard html/css

In your style section :

```
.button { /*Write whatever*/}
```

In your html:

```
<div id="buttons">
   <div class="button" @click="showOthers()">1</div>
   <div class="button" v-show="display == 'inline-block' ? false: true">2</div>
   <div class="button" v-show="display == 'inline-block' ? false : true">3</div>
</div>
```